# How do I make an INTERSECT using Eloquent Builder without having a collection

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

Here's what I got. We use `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` to build out Materialized Views in Postgres

Three tables essentially, We build the list of emails by joining subscriptions table and an emails table, then we have a resulting of list of emails of subscribers emails.

At this point, we have a third table, which has three things in it.

```
Variable_ID | Email | Value
```

The expected behavior is that a user picks a variable, (e.g. Address) and then enters a value, and we match values based on that. So then we take that subscriptions/emails joined table, and compare the variables/emails/values table and find matches.

The problem lay as say I want to do this:

$subscriptions->leftJoin('faker_email_var_table', 'faker_email_var_table'.'.email', '=', 'emails.email')
->select('faker_email_var_table'.'.email')
->where('variable_id', '1002015')->where('value', '=', '1234 Anywhere street')
->where('variable_id', '1002707')->where('value', '=', 'Smith')

That doesn't work.
Because I need match the variable_id: 1002015 AND value: 1234 Anywhere street
And then I need to match variable_id: 1002707 AND value: Smith

What works in SQL Editor is an INTERSECT.

```
SELECT var_Email_Val_Table.email
   FROM backend.subscriptions
     JOIN backend.emails ON subscriptions.email_id = emails.id
     LEFT JOIN backend.var_Email_Val_Table ON var_Email_Val_Table.email::text = emails.email
  WHERE var_Email_Val_Table.variable_id = 1002015 AND var_Email_Val_Table.value::text = '1234 Anywhere street'::text

INTERSECT

SELECT var_Email_Val_Table.email from backend.var_Email_Val_Table 
  WHERE var_Email_Val_Table.variable_id = 1002707 AND 
var_Email_Val_Table.value::text = 'Rhodes'::text

INTERSECT

 SELECT var_Email_Val_Table.email from backend.var_Email_Val_Table 
  WHERE var_Email_Val_Table.variable_id = 1002706 AND var_Email_Val_Table.value::text = 'Engineer'::text
```

But, when I try something like this:

```
$subscriptions->leftJoin(var_Email_Val_Table, var_Email_Val_Table.'.email', '=', 'emails.email')
    ->select(var_Email_Val_Table.'.email')
    ->where('variable_id', '1002015')->where('value', '=', '1234 Anywhere street')
    ->intersect(DB::table(var_Email_Val_Table)->select(var_Email_Val_Table.'.email')
    ->where('variable_id', '1002707')->where('value', '=', 'Smith'));
```

I get this error:
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::intersect()`

If this was php, I could do a series of IF conditionals to get my results, but that's not a thing in SQL.

So if any one can lend me a hand on how I can Eloquent an INTERSECT without using a collection, that would be great!

Thanks Stack Fam!

Answer (score 0):

I have this in one of my controllers, it's using `EXCEPT`, but you can change it to intersect.

I prebuild 2 separate queries. Than I do:

```php
$query = Thread::query() 
    ->fromRaw( 
        '(SELECT * FROM ((' . $unioned->toSql() . ') EXCEPT ' . $excludeExplicit->toSql() . ') AS threads) AS threads', 
        array_merge($unioned->getBindings(), $excludeExplicit->getBindings()) 
    );
```

I would be curious to learn if this is the best way though. At least it does the trick for me.

Comment: it's like eloquent is just not made for any kinda complex queries, But I will throw it up and see if it sticks! Thanks!

Comment: Well, the beauty of this is that the two separate queries are created using the query builder, and this combined query on the end returns me eloquent models. So it is like using eloquent, only with a large amount of raw SQL.

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up doing was rather specific, and I wish there was a better way. But it works.

I mentioned how this builds a Materialized View, most of which is built using Eloquent. At some point, this Eloquent builder model converts to raw SQL using `->toSql()`.
So I just concatenate the `INTERSECT`'s on after that ToSql for each additional variable added to the view.

```
$rawQuery = $subscriptions->leftJoin('variable_relational_tbl', 'variable_relational_tbl'.'email', '=', 'emails.email')
            ->select('variable_relational_tbl'.'.email')
            ->join('emails', 'subscriptions.email_id', 'emails.id')
            ->select('emails.email', 'emails.md5 as email_md5')->toSql();

$intersect = $this->buildIntersects($query['variables']);

$query = $this->formatQuery($subscriptions);
if (! empty($intersect)) {
    $query = $query.' '.$intersect;
}

// INTERSECT QUERY BUILDER
protected function buildIntersects($variables)
{
    $interstr = ' INTERSECT ';
    $subquery = '';
    $cntr = 0;
    foreach ($variables as $var) {
        if ($cntr > 0) {
            $subquery = $interstr." SELECT `variable_relational_tbl`.email FROM`variable_relational_tbl` 
                WHERE `variable_relational_tbl`.variable_id = '$var['variable_id']' AND `variable_relational_tbl`.value = '$var['variable_value']' ";
        }
    }
    return $subquery;
}
```

I build out the intersects string, with a loop
Our variables are `variable_id` and `variable_value`.
I've simplified this to show what I did of course for clarity.

But I just tack on the INTERSECTS after the `toSql()` method.
It isn't pretty, and it wouldn't work unless you are planning on making a view out of it.

But that's what I did.
Conversely, I could not find another way to get the matching rows I wanted except or intersect. Which is kind of a bummer.

I needed to remove rows from the top query and match and with Multiple cols from the `variable_relational_tbl`

Like I need all rows with var_id = 123 where value is '1234 Example Street'
AND all rows with var_id = 321 where value is '1234 Example Road'
But since a row cannot have two different var_id's INTERSECTS is the only way I could do this.

I don't know if this will ever help anyone, but Eloquent does NOT have an `INTERSECT`. And that's basically the answer to this question.