# How can I build such a query using Laravel query builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

There is a table of MySQL "Categories".

The Category model has a "hasMany" relationship that looks like this.

```
public function children(){
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

On the category editing page, in order to assign the parent category to the current one (for this I need to fill in its parent_id field), I have to generate a Select tag that will contain all rows from the category table, except for the current one and all its child categories.

```
category_id  | parent_id
------------------------
1            | NULL
2            | 1
3            | 2
4            | 3
5            | NULL
6            | 5

For example,
for category_id 1, should be selected lines with category_id [5, 6]
for category_id 2, should be selected lines with category_id [1, 5, 6]
for category_id 3, should be selected lines with category_id [1, 2, 5, 6]
for category_id 4, should be selected lines with category_id [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
for category_id 5, should be selected lines with category_id [1, 2, 3, 4]
for category_id 6, should be selected lines with category_id [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If a category has parent_id is NULL, it means that it has no parent category.

Comment: what is parent_id for? the example you gave has no parent_id and the parent_id value is not unique?

Comment: "parent_id" is a field that contains the ID of the parent category. This field is needed in order to know which parent category this category belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need so select all records `EXCEPT` recursive records from the current category.

For the recursive part, you could be used this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list

Look at the `descendantsAndSelf()` relation it includes by default.

Next you need to build the `EXCEPT` query. The query builder does not include an except function, so you need to build one yourself.

For example I have this in one of my controllers:

I have an eloquent model called `Thread`, which is a model for holding message threads. People have different view rights on these threads so I need several queries to filter out the threads they can and cannot see.

I prebuild these separate queries using the element query builder, and some I `UNION`. Than there is one query which explicitly excludes threads. And than I combine the unioned and `$excludeExplicit` queries:

```php
$query = Thread::query() 
    ->fromRaw( 
        '(SELECT * FROM ((' . $unioned->toSql() . ') EXCEPT ' . $excludeExplicit->toSql() . ') AS threads) AS threads', 
        array_merge($unioned->getBindings(), $excludeExplicit->getBindings()) 
    );
```

(See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64231210/9258054 )

The trick of this raw query is in the merging of the parameter bindings. Also, the result of this query are Eloquent models. Note that when using queries like `UNION` or `EXCEPT` you need to make sure that the `SELECT` statement of both return the same columns.

Comment: What is this class "Thread" and how to connect it in the controller? What do the $unioned, $excludeExplicit variables contain?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain it. My advice to you is to don't literally look at the answer and expect that you can use it in your code. My answer only shows how to do it, how to build a query that you need. Now it's up to you to write your own logic around it. What do you mean with 'how to connect it on the controller'?

Comment: Regarding the model "Thread", the question is closed, I already understood it. Now the question remains how to build subqueries. If it's easy for you, show the resulting query, which is executed in MySQL in your case, this can be seen from the debug panel. Then I may be able to understand what queries I should create in order to subsequently combine or exclude them.

Comment: Well, building the subqueries is not the hardest part. In your case: `$q1 = Category::whereNotNull('category_id');` (basically select all, but without getting the results immediately), `$q2 = Category::where('category_id', $current)->descendantsAndSelf();`. Then build the raw query: `$q1 EXCEPT $q2`

Comment: This line in the controller causes a very strange error
$q2 = Category::where('id', $category->parent_id)->descendantsAndSelf();

BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Staudenmeir\LaravelAdjacencyList\Eloquent\Builder::descendantsAndSelf()

Although in the model I connected this trait according to the instructions

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use \Staudenmeir\LaravelAdjacencyList\Eloquent\HasRecursiveRelationships;
}

Comment: My mistake, it should be `$q2 = Category::find($current)->descendantsAndSelf();`. First you need the actual model, therefore you need the `find` call.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around a bit in the code, I found a more elegant solution.
I am making a selection from the database using the "categories" relationship created in the "Article" model

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->morphToMany(Category::class, 'categoryable');
}
```

In doing so, I only select those items that do not have a parent category.
But thanks to the "categories" relationship, all the children go to the "Article" collection, and the tree of items is built correctly, and I don't have to do complex queries with "Join".

```
public function topMenu(){
    View::composer('layouts.header', function ($view){
        $view->with('categories', Category::whereNull('parent_id')->where('published', 1)->get());
    });
}
```